# How to mount a unix directory on windows using WSL or powershell

Tags: filesystems, mount, windows, cifs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have this directory on Unix machine which I am trying to mount on my windows machine using WSL.

```
mkdir ldp
sudo mount //IPADDRESS/var/log/Log_Files -o username=root,password='password',domain=rdc-oracle ldp
```

But this is giving me error

```
mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system
mount error(19): No such device
```

How can I get rid of this error or is there any other way to mount the unix directory on windows FS.

Comment: Sshfs is your friend. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh But.... Access the server via root? Really?

Comment: local personal server, not a problem

Comment: Try `mount -t drvfs //share ldp` - does that work?

Comment: Well, just please change it with auth_user in your question. Bad way, bad example.

Comment: @Panki doesn't work, gives error `mount: /home/himanshu/ldp: mount(2) system call failed: Host is down.
<3>init: (1951) ERROR: UtilCreateProcessAndWait:489: /bin/mount failed with status 0x2000
No error information` and host is not down

Comment: @K-att- gives error `modprobe: FATAL: Module fuse not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-18362-Microsoft`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify the operating systems involved. You mention both Unix and Linux, which one is it?

Comment: Sorry. For sshfs you not need the wsl... It's important?

Comment: 1st you can attach to the remote dir via sshfs as described in the link (for example to drive M:). After that you can mount this drive from wsl. mount -t drvfs M: /path/you/want

Comment: @K-att- could you please explain how exactly

Comment: What distribution are you running under WSL?  Also, WSL1 or WSL2?  Could you add the output of `wsl -l -v` to your question for clarity?  Thanks!

Comment: @K-att- No need to mount to a Windows drive -- WSL can directly mount sshfs.

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar Also, before we go too far down the sshfs path, can you confirm that you have SSH access to the server in question?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds  yes I do have ssh access, I am running WSL1

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds wsl2 can, indeed.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sshfs-to-mount-remote-file-systems-over-ssh In the Using Win-SSHFS to Mount Remote File Systems on Windows section. If you connect to the remote dir (as M: drive, for example), in wsl you can mount with mount -t drvfs M: /path/you/want

Comment: @K-att- That's a good catch.  I should have noticed from the fuse error that it was WSL1.